# Changing all rows in table matching a variable

Tags: mysql

I have a table called `training`. It has a column named `locations`. There are 6 different possible varchar combinations in the row ie. `location 1`, `location 2` etc.

I want to run a query that detects all instances of `location 1` and changes it to `1`.

How do I do that?

Per Sergios reply below, I've tried:

```
UPDATE training SET locations=1
```

Obviously this will change everything

Comment: @SergioTulentsev - `UPDATE training SET locations=1` obviously that changes everything

Comment: It has a row named locations? is it column or row ?

Comment: Guys, I know it's a simple question, but it's no reason to down vote.

Comment: @Paul : Downvoated... not due to it's simple. It's due to making confusion between row and column

Comment: @Teez - It was a mistake on my part. It was fixed. No reason to down vote. Ask for clarification (as you did), if clarification is not provided (which it was) THEN down vote. Thanks.

Comment: @Paul: It's for that  You should read and avoid such silly mistakes before you post. This single world changed the whole logic what you asked. do you agree ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
UPDATE training SET locations=1 WHERE locations='location 1'
```